# Should I use a site builder to create my companys page or code it

Tags: design-patterns

I am a full stack developer of over 10 years. Very experienced with React, Angular, Amazon Hosting ect. though I haven't touched sites like wordpress or squarespace. I need to create a website to promote my event production company and it's events while also providing visitors with more and more ability to sign up, apply to volunteer, and maybe eventually become a portal for my staff and promoters. Would coding such a simple site out be overkill and create too much work development work for my Event Planning buisiness?

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, I think you need to code it yourself because as what you have stated, you want it to be eventually become a portal for your staff and promoters. Since you are planning to expand the website and not make it just a landing page, it's much better to code it so that when you want to expand the website again, you won't have any problem adding some new functionalities/enhancements. Also you can customized it based on what you want so that you can attract more customers/visitors.

Remember, "First impressions lasts – and sometimes, they are the only impressions you'll have the chance to give".